# Load content in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

Trying to launch content in a modal. I have a list of products. each one has an Id and a button to load some datas in a modal for a quick over view.

UPDATE - Solution

HTML

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary call_ajax" id="ProductDescribe" data-action="GetProductDescribe" data-id="@product.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailModal">Description</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary call_ajax" id="ProductPricing" data-action="GetProductPricing" data-id="@product.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailModal">Price</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="detailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><span id="detailModalLabel"></span></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="ModalContent"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX - Get Id and ActionType from Button and pass them to Controller
Will get the specific datas back to display in modal

```
$(".call_ajax").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var actionType = $(this).attr("data-action");
 // alert(id) //check if id is comming
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("/Product/List/GetProductDetails")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        Id: id,
        ActionType: actionType
    },
      success: function (data) {
          $('#detailModal').modal('show');
          $('#detailModalLabel').empty();
          $('#ModalContent').empty();
          var detailTitle = '';
          detailTitle = data.BrandName + " - " + data.ProductName;
          var detaildata = '';
          if (actionType == 'GetProductDescribe') {
              detaildata =
                  "<div>" + data.ProductDescriptionEn + "</div>" +
                  "<div class='mt-3'>" + data.ProductDescriptionDe + "</div>" +
                  "<div class='mt-3'>" + data.ProductDescriptionFr + "</div>";
          }
          if (actionType == 'GetProductPricing') {
              detaildata =
                  "<div>" + data.VatRateTxt + "</div>" +
              "<div class='mt-3'>" + data.PriceExcVat + "</div>" +
              "<div class='mt-3'>" + data.PriceIncVat + "</div>";
          }
          $('#detailModalLabel').append(detailTitle);
          $('#ModalContent').append(detaildata);
        console.log(detaildata);
    },
    error: function(ex) {
      var r = "There is a problem";
      alert("Message: " + r);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

The Controller

```
public JsonResult GetProductDetails(int Id, string ActionType)
{
    if (ActionType == "GetProductDescribe")
    {
        query = _context.ProductDescribeFulls.Where(pd => pd.ProductId == Id).Single();
    }

    if (ActionType == "GetProductPricing")
    {
        query = _context.ProductPricingFulls.Where(pd => pd.ProductId == Id).Single();
    }
    var productDetail = query;
    return Json(productDetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Thanks to @Swati for the help!

Comment: Hi , what doesn't work in your code ? Also how does that controller code gets called using ajax ?

Comment: Hi, I think the code is ok, I just don't know how to write the function in the view to call and get the datas from the controller

Comment: You can use ajax here . So, on click of that button grab value of `id` which you need to send to backend and pass same in backend. After you did this let me output which you are getting under `success` function of ajax.

Comment: I did add a function to start with, but I am completely new and novice here!

Comment: Where is `id` which you need to send in your html ?

Comment: Id is @product.Id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225042/discussion-between-swati-and-philippe).

Comment: Thanks @Swati. Got it right now, but I have one question for you (chat still open)